# Which app changes lead to a reinstall/replace when updating the app?

Tags: android

When I update an app and only make few changes like increasing the versionCode the app just updates the changed content but if I make several changes the app reinstalls/is being replaced by the new version.

So far so good but where can I find the information which changes will lead to the reinstallation (maybe changes in the package, removed or added classes etc.)?

Context: I want to update a device (Grandstream GXV3370) via adb without user input and it is an app which replaces the default phone app. When the app just updates the changed content, it is still the "default phone app" but if it reinstalls, the standard "phone" app is the "default phone app" so the user has to close the app and make my app the "default phone app" again.
If I could avoid the app from being reinstalled the user input could also be avoided.

Comment: For my own issue I could find the reason why the "default phone app" changed: We made a change in the package of the PhoneService so the permission could not be set again after reinstallation.